# What is the right way to send PHP Mail Headers?

Tags: php, gmail

I have run into a weird problem. Some clients would like to be able to use gmail canned responses with emails submitted through their site's web form. Up until canned responses, everything has worked fine. Simply clicking "reply" on an email from the web form submission worked like a charm and replied to the sender. However, CannedResponses from Google Labs is proving to be a problem. Canned responses is auto replying to `myUsername@myWebserver.com` (changed for privacy reasons, obviously) rather than the senders email address. Am I doing something wrong with the headers, or is there another workaround? Code below:

```
function send_mail($to, $subject, $from, $messageData=array()) {

    // Build the message here

    $mailheaders = "From: $from";
    $mailheaders .= "\r\n";
    $mailheaders .= "Reply-To: $from";

    return mail($to, $subject, $message, $mailheaders);
}
```

**Edit for clarification:**
What I mean by auto replies being sent to `myUsername@myWebserver.com` is my username `at` my dreamhost web server - ps0000.dreamhostps.com

Comment: doesn't your mail sever have an auto-reply option ?

Comment: Google is the mail server - they use Google Apps for Business

Comment: i think i get it now, best option stop using mail() so you have real control (switch to phpmailer or swiftmailer libs) or add the infamous **-f** parameter to mail()

Comment: @Dagon That totally worked, post that as an answer and I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While i strongly recommend you switch to a mailer library such as phpmailer or swiftmailer, in the short term you can fix it by using the -f parameter in your mail() function

Comment: Switched to phpmailer - I'm never looking back. Thanks!

Comment: neat, i get a referral fee from them (kidding)