# How to send email out by php or javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

After insert the user information to database by php. I want to send user email to tell them the good news.How do we go about doing that? Thanks.

I have used the following code from w3school, but it doesn't work.

```
<?php
 $to = "someone@example.com";
 $subject = "Test mail";
 $message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
 $from = "someonelse@example.com";
 $headers = "From:" . $from;
 mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
 echo "Mail Sent.";
 ?>
```

Comment: This can easily be found with a quick Google or StackOverflow search... lacks research.

Comment: That code seriously does not work? Did you get any errors? Please be more specific than "doesn't work"...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the right way to send PHP Mail Headers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912788/what-is-the-right-way-to-send-php-mail-headers)

Comment: no error shows, just no email in my mail mox

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you skipped some research...

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

mail() oftens sends the mail into spam folders. Some mail providers will also block those mails because their headers are incomplete. Worse : some hosting providers just block this function. It you want something clean, use a SMTP connection. Here's another reference :

- http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm

Then, use one of yours emails accounts for SMTP settings (e.g. a GMail account created for your site, whatever).

Comment: Where is "mail.php" in your reference?

Comment: It is part of the PEAR Mail Package. If you have PEAR and PEAR Mail installed as required, Mail.php should be part of PHP include_path, and found by your script instruction :)

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy:

```
$sendto = "anyemail@email.com";
$subject = "My subject!";
$message = "This is an email message!";
mail($sendto,$subject,$message);
```

You also should look at more advanced stuff like headers... check all that out right here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php